# Formula for PROPER Case with Apostrophe

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm using Google Sheets glued together (not be me) from multiple sources where some of the names are in all caps. In trying to clean web-ready content, I have good success with the `PROPER()` function except when it is a name with an apostrophe.

If the cell contains `SMITTY'S` running it through the `PROPER()` function returns `Smitty'S` and is ugly. Any clever ideas around this?

Comment: wrap it into `REGEXREPLACE()`

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 16 times.

Answer (score 1):

If your string to be converted is in `A1`, place in `B2` a dummy alphabetic string which would never actually appear, and use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'",$B$2)),$B$2,"'")
```

If the dummy string ever appears in any string, simply change it.

Answer (score -1):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(PROPER(C15); "'S"; "'s")
```

[image: 1]